# mysql disk I/O 100%

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

MySQL database is showing disk i/o utilization around 100% continuously. A database server is having 24 GB ram.

We tried to optimize queries but nothing worked much.

Please check the current configuration parameters shown below:

- **Parameter**                   **Current Value**
- key_buffer_size                     536.88 MB
- query_cache_size                   268.43 MB
- tmp_table_size                     40368.70 MB
- innodb_buffer_pool_size             12884.90 MB
- innodb_additional_mem_pool_size    8.4MB
- innodb_log_buffer_size             134.22 MB
- max_connections                 6000
- sort_buffer_size                   8.38
- read_buffer_size                   8.38 MB
- read_rnd_buffer_size               8.38 MB
- join_buffer_size            0.26 MB
- thread_stack                    0.26 MB
- binlog_cache_size               0.03 MB

Please suggest if you find anything wrong in the current configuration.

Comment: Install MySQL Workbench. The "performance reports" tab will give you any details you want, especially "high cost sql statements" and "database schema (index) statistics". Also did you try using any tools like [this one](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) ?

Comment: Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%used%'; for analysis, and complete text results of MySQLTuner.pl (perl) script request.

Comment: @Avadhut Pisal Have you implemented these suggestions? Please comment on results - positive/negative - have not tried them. Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%used%'; for analysis, and complete text results of MySQLTuner.pl (perl) script request. Post ONLY if you would like additional performance enhancing suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second=RPS - Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf (or my.ini) [mysqld] section

```
query_cache_size=50M  # from 268M to reduce CPU cycles used in management of QC
tmp_table_size=256M  # from 40G for ~ 1% of RAM a reasonable limit
max_heap_table_size=256M  # to match size of tmp_table_size, using 1% of RAM
sort_buffer_size=1M  # from 8M allocated per connection - next 2 are per connect also
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 8M to reduce volume of data retrieved by 95%
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from 8M to reduce volume of data retrieved by 95%
```

Apply all on 1 stop/start of your instance.  Please post comments on positive/negative results after 24 hours of normal workday uptime.

Comment: @Avadhut Pisal Have you implemented these suggestions?  Please comment on results - positive/negative - have not tried them.  Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%used%'; for analysis, and complete text results of MySQLTuner.pl (perl) script request. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Swapping like mad!!

Do not blindly increase tunables.  Go back to the defaults except for one:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
```

Set that to about 70% of available RAM.